# How to use existing data model (Java object POJO classes) and get the full JSON string using Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

I already have the POJO Java classes (can assert the response using the mapper), I also have the JSON file (if needed)

1. I need to convert the POJO classes into full JSON string
2. I need to replace an object in the JSON

What are my options? If I am calling the object, it's been overriden and I get empty JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the method `writeValueAsString(Object value)` of class [ObjectMapper](https://www.javadoc.io/static/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.13.0-rc1/index.html?com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). Just pass to it your pojo and get JSON String. Other ways are to use various methods `writeValue(...)` or methods `writeFor(...)` that return `ObjectWriter` class. All in all a trivial task

Comment: I get empty json or reference to the main pojo class.
1. I go to the: https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
2. I paste my json their
3. I convert my json toi pojo classes and use them.
4. Now I want to use the classes to genrate json

Comment: you need to give an instance of your pojo to method writeValueAsString(Object value). For instance:
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setSomeProp("My Value");
...
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String myJsonStr = om.writeValueAsString(myClass);

Answer (score 0):

1. For converting the POJO to Json, you can use:

a) `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` class:

```
private void convert() throws JsonProcessingException {
    SomePOJO pojo = new SomePOJO();
    pojo.setColumnVal("someVal");
    pojo.setId("someId");
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo));
}
```

and it will give:

```
{"id":"someId","columnVal":"someVal"}
```

b) `com.google.gson.Gson` class:

```
private void convert() throws JsonProcessingException {
    SomePOJO pojo = new SomePOJO();
    pojo.setColumnVal("someVal");
    pojo.setId("someId");

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(pojo));
}
```

2. To replace object in the json, you will like to map the json to a class first, you can use either of the `objectMapper` or `Gson` for this.

a) using `Gson`:

```
private void convert() throws JsonProcessingException {
    String json = "{\"id\":\"someId\",\"columnVal\":\"someVal\"}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    SomePOJO pojo = gson.fromJson(json, SomePOJO.class);
    System.out.println("Before change: " + pojo.getColumnVal());
    pojo.setColumnVal("otherVal");
    System.out.println("After Change: " + pojo.getColumnVal());
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(pojo));
}
```

this will give you:

```
Before change: someVal
After Change: otherVal
{"id":"someId","columnVal":"otherVal"}
```

b) using `objectMapper`:

```
private void convert() throws JsonProcessingException {
    String json = "{\"id\":\"someId\",\"columnVal\":\"someVal\"}";
    SomePOJO pojo = objectMapper.readValue(json, SomePOJO.class);
    System.out.println("Before change: " + pojo.getColumnVal());
    pojo.setColumnVal("otherVal");
    System.out.println("After Change: " + pojo.getColumnVal());
    System.out.println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(pojo));
}
```

this will give the same result.

These are the most convenient ways to do the jobs.